# how to put an "interactive" map in a website?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a car pooling system, the user can go from a state to another state, the user fills in a form and in the form he chooses from what state to what state they want to go, I want to show a map with the chosen states to be highlighted, I have no idea how to do it, or what to use, I don't want to click on the map, i just the values taken from the form before to be shown on it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan hello, the problem is, i have no attempts, i have no idea where to start

Comment: [How about here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+put+an+%E2%80%9Cinteractive%E2%80%9D+map+in+a+website%3F)

Comment: I was not being witty. I genuinely find (and SO's [ask] agrees) that you FIRST do some research, as in the simple gesture of googling the title of your question, find some solution that may or may not fully answer your question and THEN write a question containing a [mcve] of what you tried (and partially failed with)

Comment: @mplungjan alright, then i apologize for my comment and ill do more research